# Incorrect geocoding for a specific address in googleMap API v3

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I have an error with a specific address in the googleMaps API v3. I've verified that the address is correct before being geocoded but the lat/long I get is incorrect.

Here is the load function with the function used to geocode the user's address:

```
function load() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var centerAddress = membreAddress();
}
function membreAddress(){
    if(document.getElementById("gmapCoords")){
        var address = document.getElementById("gmapCoords").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } 
            else {
                alert("Le geocodage n\'a pu etre effectue pour la raison suivante: " + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The load function is called on the body onLoad event.
Those functions works with every other address in the same format as the one I'm having issues with. The format I use is address, city, postal code.

Is it possible with the GMap api V3 to use the address directly instead of the incorrect geocoding position? If it's not, is there some way to geocode the address with something else than the gmap API and pass those to the API instead?

Comment: What is the address you are having trouble with? If you know the correct location, you can use the coordinates rather than the geocoder.

Comment: The address I'm having issues with is 276 King ouest(West), Sherbrooke, QC. But the geocoder gives me the coordinates for 276 King Est(East). Is there documentation on how use the coordinates instead of the geocoder?

Comment: [Both those addresses give unique results from the geocoder for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=276%20King%20ouest%28West%29,%20Sherbrooke,%20QC.&geocode=1&addr2=276%20King%20est%28East%29,%20Sherbrooke,%20QC.&geocode=2).  To set the marker using coordinates, remove the call to the geocoder and just set the marker directly: `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(<latcoord>,<lngcoord>)});`, where <latcoord>,<lngcoord> are the known good coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I've finally been able to correct the issue with the geocoder. I used the same format used in your example (I removed the postalCode in my case) and it started displaying at the right place.